# ubuntu web server stops responding trying to find root cause

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04

I know enough linux to be dangerous but not a lot in the way of troubleshooting. So the issue I have is I have an ubuntu web server running a package called [teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). The issue I am having is about once a week or so the web server stops responding but is still pingable on the network. I can either reboot the server to bring it back up or if I just initiate `/etc/init.d/networking restart` the webserver starts working again. Again even though I am not losing IP connectivity I can still access the web from the server but it doesn't answer any http requests. How can I find what is causing this? Where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

And if you remove teamcity does it still occur?

I've never used Teamcity on a non windows platform, so can't help with that

But I do know apache and Ubuntu.

Instead of /etc/init.d/networking restart, does it make any difference if you try

apache2ctl restart

If that allows your web server to work, then it sound's like an issue with Apaches binding to the network card, if not and you have to use the networking script, then it may be a deeper issue with your network settings.

Possibly, the network card itself, so you may want to try another network card if possible.